# Toggle Show And Hide Only Some Table Rows using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html-table, row, show, hidden

I am trying to **show/hide** some rows of my table with a button using Angularjs.
Please see attached images as your reference.

On this table some rows needs to be visible at the first look, when I click on "Show more" button it should show the rest of the rows. Again when I click on the "Show Less" button this part needs to be hidden.

I appreciate if anyone could help.

First look:

[image: First look]

Second look:

[image: Second look]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I need to do it with Angularjs. But I do not know how! I am thinking to write a function to count the row numbers if possible, then based on that status it will toggle the Show/Hide button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is Angular JS Code
>
> ```js
> var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
>  app.controller("tableCtrl",function($scope){
>    $scope.showhide=function(){//initial limit is 4 you cange it here
>    if($scope.showless){$scope.limit=4; $scope.text="Show More";}
>    else{ $scope.limit=$scope.tableData.length; $scope.text="Show Less";}
> $scope.showless=!$scope.showless;
>   }
>
>   $scope.limit=4;
>   $scope.showless=true;
>
> //example 10 rows
> $scope.tableData=[{th:"th",td1:"td",td2:"td",td3:"td"},
>      {th:"th",td1:"td",td2:"td",td3:"td"},
>      {th:"th",td1:"td",td2:"td",td3:"td"},
>      {th:"th",td1:"td",td2:"td",td3:"td"},
>      {th:"th",td1:"td",td2:"td",td3:"td"},
>      {th:"th",td1:"td",td2:"td",td3:"td"},
>      {th:"th",td1:"td",td2:"td",td3:"td"},
>      {th:"th",td1:"td",td2:"td",td3:"td"},
>      {th:"th",td1:"td",td2:"td",td3:"td"},
>      {th:"th",td1:"td",td2:"td",td3:"td"}];
>
>      $scope.showhide();
>   });
> ```
>
> ```html
>  
> <html>
>
> <head>
>     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js">
>     </script>
> </head>
>
> <body ng-app="myApp">
>     <div ng-controller="tableCtrl">
>         <table border="2" style="border-color: red">
>             <tbody>
>                 <tr ng-repeat="x in tableData|limitTo:limit">
>                     <th>{{x.th}}</th>
>                     <td>{{ x.td1 }}</td>
>                     <td>{{ x.td2 }}</td>
>                     <td>{{ x.td3}}</td>
>                 </tr>
>                 <tr>
>                     <td colspan="4"><button ng-click="showhide()" style="width: 100%">{{text}}</button></td>
>                 </tr>
>             </tbody>
>         </table>
>     </div>
>     </body>
>     </html>
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much ArunKumarmn, for the reply. My question is how I can modify my **tableData** here? Cause I need to fill my cell with something like this: <tr><th>Difference</th><td ng-repeat="scenarioSummary in model.loanSummaries">{{scenarioSummary.difference === 0 ? null : (scenarioSummary.difference | currency : '$' : '0')}}</td></tr>

Comment: can you share your code with JSfiddle or something like that. So that i can edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code as per your need..

> HTML

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in dummyData track by $index" ng-hide="$index >= loadIndex">
    <td>{{x.id}}</td>
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.status}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" ng-click="showMore()" ng-if="loadIndex < dummyData .length">Show More</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="showLess()" ng-if="loadIndex >= dummyData .length">Show Less</button>
```

> Controller

```
$scope.loadIndex = 6 // increment the loadindex as per yourr need       
        $scope.showMore = function() {
        // don't increment if at the end of the list
            if ($scope.loadIndex < $scope.dummyData .length) {
              $scope.loadIndex += 5;
            }
        };  
        $scope.showLess = function() {
           if ($scope.loadIndex >= $scope.dummyData .length) {
              $scope.loadIndex -= 5;
            }
        };  

$scope.dummyData = [{
    "id":1,
    "name":"abc1",
    "status":"open"
},{
    "id":2,
    "name":"abc2",
    "status":"open"
},{
    "id":3,
    "name":"abc3",
    "status":"open"
},{
    "id":4,
    "name":"abc4",
    "status":"open"
},{
    "id":5,
    "name":"abc5",
    "status":"open"
},{
    "id":6,
    "name":"abc6",
    "status":"open"
},{
    "id":7,
    "name":"abc7",
    "status":"open"
},{
    "id":8,
    "name":"abc8",
    "status":"open"
},{
    "id":9,
    "name":"abc9",
    "status":"open"
},{
    "id":10,
    "name":"abc10",
    "status":"open"
}]
```